# Random rod split possibility problem, should I take it discrete or continuous?

Tags: probability

Question: A rod which is in unit length, split it randomly into 3 parts: left, middle and right. What is the possibility that the middle part is the longest one?

I knew the problem could be solved by taking the coordinate of split point as $x_1$ and $x_2$, then solve it geometrically on the $(x_1,x_2)$ plane.

But can I consider it a discrete problem, that each one of the 3 parts could be either the longest, middle or shortest part, then the possibility is obviously $\frac{1}{3}$, which is identical to the geometry method?

Comment: It's not obvious that the distributions of the three lengths are identical.  if you can prove that, then you can do it discretely.  Hint:  Suppose you were choosing two points on a circle instead of on a line.

Comment: @user2661923  The way I read the problem:  two points are chosen uniformly at random on the interval $[0,1]$.  These two points divide the interval into three lengths, and the problems asks for the probabilities that each is the longest.  Clearly the two outer ones have a symmetry but I don't think it is instantly clear that the middle one has the same distribution.  That seems like it is worth a proof.

Comment: @lulu I just deleted my previous comment(s), because I realized that there will only be $~2~$ cuts, rather than $~3~$ cuts.  After re-thinking, while I think that your interpretation is plausible, an alternate interpretation is equally plausible.  Suppose that the first cut is at point $~x,~$ and is arbitrarily set to be the *lower* cut.  Then, the 2nd cut will represent a number chosen at random from $~(x,1),~$ rather than $~(0,1). ~$  Re-stating, I think that the phrase "split it randomly into three parts" is ambiguous, and that the exact method of choosing the numbers must be described.

Comment: **To the Original Poster**: Unclear to me if your answer of (1/3) is correct, given lulu's interpretation, or my (alternative) interpretation.  However, there is a 3rd (also plausible) interpretation, under which the answer is **definitely** (1/3):  Three numbers $~a,b,c~$ are each randomly chosen from $~(0,1),~$ with $~b~$ representing the **center**.  Then, these numbers are **scaled** to $~ka, ~kb, ~kc, ~$ where $~k = \dfrac{1}{a + b + c} \implies ka + kb + kc = 1.$

Comment: Sorry for the unclear statement, the problem is from a Chinese probability question set and the editor may want me to use the geometric idea, who himself may not define the question well. Perhaps I will translate the solution later, in which the editor thought we should take a cut first, and the second cut is taken from the rest of the rod. Thank you for the answers anyway.

Comment: It's not difficult to show that the middle piece is the longest if and only if either$$x_2>\max\left(2x_1,\frac{1+x_1}{2}\right)$$or$$x_1>\max\left(2x_2,\frac{1+x_2}{2}\right)\ ,$$it is the shortest if and only if either$$x_1<x_2<\min\left(2x_1,\frac{1+x_1}{2}\right)$$or$$x_2<x_1<\min\left(2x_2,\frac{1+x_2}{2}\right)\ ,$$and that each of these disjoint subsets of the unit square has area $\ \frac{1}{6}\ .$

Comment: Thus, if $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ are independent and uniformly distributed over the unit interval, then each piece does indeed have the same probability of  $\ \frac{1}{3}\ $  of being the longest piece, the shortest piece or neither. Nevertheless, since the lengths of the end pieces have a different distribution from that of the middle piece—the former having density  $\ 2(1−x)\ $  and mean  $\ \frac{1}{6}\ $  and the latter density  $\ 2x\ $  and mean  $\ \frac{2}{3}\ $ —I agree with the other commenters that there appears to be no obvious simple argument for arriving at these conclusions.

Comment: "...and the second cut is taken from the rest of the rod..."  This implies that the (plausible) interpretation of @lulu is not what the problem composer intended.  Instead, if the first cut is at $~x,~$ then the next cut is taken at random from $~(x,1),~$ rather than $~(0,1).$